# Get information on a website with php

Tags: php

I 've been reading some of the topic about this. However, I dont quite understand how to do it. Need some help. 
I want to get information from a website. For example, I want to get information such as Market, Open, High, Low, Last, Change, Pct from http://quotes.ino.com/exchanges/futboard/

Thank you for ur help.

Comment: At least try to ask, if this site has API to communicate.

Answer (score 4):

This is called "screen scraping". It usually involves obtaining the HTML from the page (such as with [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)), then parsing the HTML.

Before doing this, you should first obtain permission from the owner of the web site. Also, if they have an API, it would be the preferred method.

Comment: You could use a DOM parser or string parser as well.